# Stack being represented by a scheme/manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, algebraic-stacks, differentiable-stacks

On page $10$  of the survey article *[Algebraic stacks](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911199)*, by T. Gomez (arXiv:math/9911199), we have following result

> If a stack has an object with an automorphism other than the identity, then the stack can not be represented by a scheme.

Is the converse true?

Suppose I know only automorphism of any object are trivial automorphisms, then can I say that that stack is coming from a manifold/scheme.

Is there any way to construct such scheme/manifold.

Is it practical to check if each object has only trivial automorphisms.

Edit : There is some slight confusion regarding the notion of "no non trivial automorphisms". I want to clear that (mostly to myself).

A stack over a category(site) $\mathcal{C}$ can be seen in two ways.

One way as a category $\mathcal{D}$ with a functor $\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ that is fibered in groupoids with some extra condition. Another way as a functor(almost) $F:\mathcal{C}^{op}\rightarrow (\text{Gpd})$ where $\text{Gpd}$ means the (2)category of groupoids.

To understand the notion of "no non trivial automorphisms" it is better (I think so) to see stack as $F:\mathcal{C}^{op}\rightarrow (\text{Gpd})$. By no non trivial automorphism for $F$ we mean the following :

Let $U$ be an object in $\mathcal{C}$. Then $F(U)$ is a groupoid. Let $x,y\in X(U)$ then, the set of arrows from $x,y$ denoted by $\text{Hom}(x,y)$ iseither empty or singleton. If this holds for each object  $U$ of $\mathcal{C}$ and for each pair of objects $x,y\in F(U)$. Then, we say that this stack has no objects with non trivial automorphisms.

See a stack as a functor from category $\mathcal{D}$ to $\mathcal{C}$ say $F:\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$. Let $U$ be an object in $\mathcal{C}$. Look at the fiber category $\mathcal{D}(U)$. Let $x,y$ be objects in $\mathcal{D}(U)$ and $Hom(x,y)$ denote the arrows from $x,y$. If $Hom(x,y)$ is either singleton or empty for each pair of objects $x,y$ in $\mathcal{D}(U)$ and for each object $U$ in $\mathcal{C}$ then, we say the stack $\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ has no non trivial automorphisms.

Comment: This is definitely not true in the context of the article you quote --- essentially you are asking if all sheaves on the category of schemes (in your favorite subcanonical topology) are representable. There are many counterexamples; for example, there are algebraic spaces (which have an etale cover by representables) which are not schemes.

Comment: @DanielLitt I am familiar with differential geometric version of stacks and only recently started reading algebraic stacks. I do not know much about algebraic spaces... Even if you think this question is very trivial, I shamelessly request you to write (when you are free) little more details as as answer (only if you think this question is not off topic here)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all objects of a stack have trivial automorphism groups then it is equivalent to a sheaf, as pointed out by Daniel Litt in the comments. Pick your favourite non-representable sheaf as a counterexample to the claim that the stack is representable. For instance, on the site of manifolds, defined to be Hausdorff, paracompact, locally Euclidean topological spaces, consider the stack presented by a groupoid associated to an equivalence relation with non-Hausdorff quotient. In fact *any* equivalence relation such that the quotient is not a manifold will do (cf [the irrational flow on a torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_flow_on_the_torus#Irrational_winding_of_a_torus)).

Comment: Ok, if you can, please give reference for the result “If all objects of a stack have trivial automorphism groups then it is equivalent to a sheaf”... Assuming this, I think I got the rough idea.. there are non representable sheaves... so, that stack associated to sheaf which is not representable is not representable.. Ok..

Comment: If all objects of a stack $S^{op} \to Gpd$ have trivial automorphism groups it is naturally isomorphic to a functor $S^{op} \to Set \hookrightarrow Gpd$, and since the stack satisfies descent, the functor $S^{op} \to Set$ satisfies descent and hence is a sheaf. No reference required.

Comment: Ok...  there is some difference in notations.. Both of us are using base category as $S$... I am seeing stack as a category $\mathcal{D}$ with a functor $\mathcal{D}\rightarrow S$ with (among other) a condition that given an object $U$ of $S$ the fiber $\mathcal{D}(U)$ is a groupoid... This gives a functor $S^{op}\rightarrow Gpd$... This is the notation you are using... Ok.. Giving a Grothendieck topology on $S$ you can ask if this functor is a sheaf or not..

Comment: I do not know if there is any notion of calling a functor $S^{op}\rightarrow Gpd$ to be a sheaf but I know when to call a functor $S^{op}\rightarrow (Set)$ to be a sheaf... I am trying to see how you are factoring the functor $S^{op}\rightarrow Gpd$  by $S^{op}\rightarrow Set$...

Comment: A stack $X\colon S^{op}\to Gpd$ is a sheaf by definition if it factors through $Set\hookrightarrow Gpd$. In this way one has an inclusion of the category of sheaves in the 2-category of stacks. If $X(s)$ has trivial automorphism groups then it is an equivalence relation and so is equivalent, as a groupoid, to the set $X(s)/~$ of equivalence classes. If this is so for all objects $s$ of $S$, then by the universal property of quotients there is a functor $X/~\colon s\mapsto X(s)/~$ and a natural equiv (not iso, my mistake) $X \to X/~$ of functors $S^{op}\to Gpd$, and $X/~$ factors through $Set$.

Comment: I think I got it mostly.. I will figure out details.. So, when people say "no non trivial automorphisms" they mean $X(s)$ is singleton set where $s\in S$... I should not think of this as $Hom(x,x)=\{e\}$ for $x\in \mathcal{D}$... It is about elements in $S$ and not about elements in $\mathcal{D}$.. RIght?

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik: When people say "no nontrivial automorphisms" they mean $X(s)$ is equivalent to a rigid groupoid (one for which Hom(x,y) is either empty or a singleton) for every $s$.

Comment: You mean $Hom(s,s)$?? @Qfwfq

Comment: @PK: no, I do mean the arrows of the category X(s)

Comment: @PK: consider the quotient groupoid of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by the vertical translation action of $\mathbb{R}$, $(x,y)\mapsto(x,y+v)$, $v\in\mathbb{R}$. The quotient -whatever it is- should be representable and equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$, so have no nontrivial automorphisms. Look at the object $s:=\{*\}$ (one point) of Manifolds. The groupoid $X(s)$ has a lot of objects: all the points of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but points $p=(x,y)$ and $p'=(x',y')$ on the same orbit are joined by the unique arrow corresponding to the unique $v\in\mathbb{R}$ for which $y'=y+v$. Points in distinct orbits aren't joined.

Comment: @Qfwfq It was 5 am for me (5 hours ago :P) so could not concentrate much. Can you please write that as an answer.. I think I even misunderstood what it means to say “no non trivial automorphisms”...

Comment: @PK: I think my comment isn't a good fit for an answer: it just illustrates that the "$\Rightarrow$" holds (representable $\Rightarrow$ "there are no nontrivial automorphisms") even when strictly speaking (pun intended) there *are* arrows in X(s). Your question was more about the converse "$\Leftarrow$", which this answer by David Roberts shows not to hold.

Comment: I have got the idea.. There is no point in waiting more, so I accepted the answer.. Thanks..